# Reynolds limits on laminar flow between irregular plates (fracture)

Tags: fluid-dynamics, porous-media

I'm trying to understand the limits of laminar flow in a system comprised of two plates of varying width. The idea is to model a naturally fractured system and understand up to when flow and pressure can be considered linear. I understand reynolds is the standard way to do it, but I have several reference limits: [here](https://inis.iaea.org/collection/NCLCollectionStore/_Public/26/034/26034259.pdf) (Hydraulic  Conductivity  of  Rock  Fractures -Zimmerman & Bodvarsson, 1994) the limit is suggested at 1e3, [here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/259849241_Flow_through_porous_media_at_moderate_Reynolds_number) (Flow through porous media at moderate Reynolds number - Hellström & Lundström, 2006), it talks about 1e2 to 1e3, and I understand the standard "moody" transition is around 2.3e3.

I wanted to know if there is a reference value, or if it can be determined (which parameters are needed for the system) and how.

Comment: Minor comment to the post (v2): Please consider to mention explicitly author, title, etc. of links, so it is possible to reconstruct link in case of link rot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is indeed a proposed way of calculating the value for specific conditions. I am aware that because of the brevity of my answer, this should be a comment, but I am yet not able to post comments. Take a look at Equation 3.40 of the paper https://doi.org/10.1016/B978-0-08-098346-2.00003-X
That should help.